# PHP mbstring, xml and curl setup

Tags: apt, apache2, php, curl, xml

My script installation rquires the following setup:

```
sudo apt update,
sudo apt install php-curl,
sudo apt install php-mbstring,
sudo apt install php-xml,
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After running the setup, the site is not working. Still as asking for setup. Please how can i fixed this.

[image: mbstring, xml and curl setup]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? PHP 8.0.14 does not ship with 21.10 or 22.04 (pre-release), which makes it difficult to say this is an *Ubuntu* issue ... 

Comment: Version Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: 20.04 ships with PHP 7.x, so you are likely using ondrej or another PPA for your PHP packages. However, as there’s nothing in your question saying where you’re getting PHP 8 from, it’s difficult to offer an answer that is sure to be correct 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead:

```
sudo apt install php8.0-curl
sudo apt install php8.0-mbstring
sudo apt install php8.0-xml
```

***php-curl*** that you installed:

> This package is a dependency package, which depends on Debian's default
> PHP version (currently 8.1).

So php-curl usually "links" to the latest php version installed, in my case 8.1. (Meaning it only installed php8.1-curl)

If this does not enable the above modules automatically, try:

```
sudo phpenmod -v 8.0 curl
```

###### Syntax

```
phpenmod -v <PHP VERSION> <MODULE NAME>
```

Alternatively, if this does not work, you could try to look at ***"/etc/php/8.0/apache2/conf.d"*** and symlink the modules ini files there to enable them.

Comment: sudo apt install php8.0-curl
sudo apt install php8.0-mbstring
sudo apt install php8.0-xml. The above set-up works. I truly appreciate. Thanks a lot.